# How to get current blueprint state(event) in FuseFabric

Tags: java, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

I using FuseFabric:karaf.
This code return state from interface BundleInfo(ACTIVE). How i can to take BluePrint state(Created)?

```
    private void getState() {
    Container[] containers = fabricService.getContainers();
    for (Container c : containers) {
        c.getJmxUrl();
        ContainerTemplate ct = new ContainerTemplate(c, "admin", "admin",
                false);
        BundleInfo[] bfArray = c.getBundles(ct);
        for (BundleInfo bf : bfArray) {
            bf.getState(); 
        }
    }
}
```

START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: -1
   ID   State         Blueprint      Level  Name
[   0] [Active     ] [ Created    ] [    0] System Bundle (4.0.3.redhat-60024)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the state from the `fabricService` as shown in the container-list command

- https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/blob/master/fabric/fabric-commands/src/main/java/io/fabric8/commands/ContainerListAction.java#L123

Comment: Can i do the same in fabric 7.2.0?
I didn't find method getDataStore or analogue in sources.

Comment: Ah no JBoss Fuse 6.0 does not include the git datastore. This requires JBoss Fuse 6.1 onwards.

Comment: Is it exclusive way? May be there is another way?